# how to write pandas data frame into csv file? How to remove list array braces ([]) from final dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, data-science

how to write final panda data frame value into pipe delimiter csv file. current final data frame column contains list of array (`[]`) values. how to remove list array braces(`[]`) from dictionary list values and how to write in final csv file with comma separate values and pipe delimiter(`|`) csv file and line data should not break into new lines with `""` values.

```
new_ids_simple = {0: {'d_ph_num': ['9812345670','9123456200'], 'r_vid': ['DQR695919','DQR695921','DQR696123','DQR69124','DQR695763','DQR695623','DQR69125','DQR696234','DQR695128'], 'unique_cust_id': 202000001}, 1: {'d_ph_num': ['9123456914'], 'r_vid': ['DQR626679'], 'unique_cust_id': 202000002}, 2: {'d_ph_num': [''], 'r_vid': ['DQR040140'], 'unique_cust_id': 202000003}, 3: {'d_ph_num': ['9123456174'], 'r_vid': ['DQR041822'], 'unique_cust_id': 202000004}}

print(new_ids_simple)

mdf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_ids_simple,orient='index')
mdf['d_ph_num'] = mdf['d_ph_num'].apply(pd.unique)
mdf['r_vid'] = mdf['r_vid'].apply(pd.unique)

mdf.to_csv('/data/dmart/output/p_data1.csv', sep="|" ,index=False)
```

corrupted csv file created with below data set, it's not in proper format:

```
d_ph_num|r_vid|u_id
['9812345670' '9123456200']|"['DQR695919' 'DQR695921' 'DQR696123' 'DQR69124' 'DQR695763' 'DQR695623' 'DQR69125' 
'DQR696234' 'DQR695128']"|202000001
['9123456914']|['DQR626679']|202000002
[nan]|['DQR040140']|202000003
['9123456174']|['DQR041822']|202000004
```

final expected csv file format data:

```
d_ph_num|r_vid|u_id
('9812345670','9123456200')|('DQR695919','DQR695921','DQR696123','DQR69124','DQR695763','DQR695623','DQR69125','DQR696234','DQR695128')|202000001
('9123456914')|('DQR626679')|202000002
|('DQR040140')|202000003
('9123456174')|('DQR041822')|202000004
```

Comment: You should make the example fully reproducible, so it is easier to check the problem and find a solution. Right now, is not straight forward to get the dataset you are showing, and at least if I use the dataframe you show I don't obtain the same output

Comment: @Jalo i have re-created with sample input dataset. try to create csv file now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is due to the conversion to arrays when you apply the `pd.unique` function. Since you want to show the values with the parenthesis, I would convert back the values to tuples before sending the dataframe to the csv file (or lists if square brackets are enough):

```
mdf['d_ph_num'] = mdf['d_ph_num'].apply(tuple)
mdf['r_vid'] = mdf['r_vid'].apply(tuple)
mdf.to_csv('/data/dmart/output/p_data1.csv', sep="|" ,index=False)
```

Note that this approach is not ideal for very large datasets, since you would be converting all the values to arrays, and then back to a list or tuple. If that is the case, I would consider creating a custom function that reproduces the behaviour of `pd.unique` and directly places the values into a tuple.

Comment: 1) i have large data set for creating unique customers.
2) final csv file we will load into database so data should not slipt into multiple lines.

Comment: You are asking too many question in one single question, which is not the way this website works. Also, it would seem like you want someone to fix a whole assignment for you, which is not how this works either. I offered you a solution for removing the square brackets and the wrong line break, but I won't spend my time fixing your whole assignment

Comment: The exact behaviour you are asking for is out of the scope of the `pandas.to_csv` behaviour. If your code specifications are very strict, I recommend you to start making your own piece of code that manually creates a csv file and sends data to it

Answer (score 0):

The conversion python panda data frame from an array to a string (inside the data frame):

```
mdf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_ids_simple,orient='index')
mdf['d_ph_num'] = mdf['d_ph_num'].apply(pd.unique)
mdf['r_vid'] = mdf['r_vid'].apply(pd.unique)

#To convert from an array to a string (inside the data frame)
mdf['r_vid'] = mdf['r_vid'].apply(', '.join)

#To convert from a float number type array to string 
mdf['d_ph_nm'] = [','.join(map(str, l)) for l in mdf['d_ph_nm']]

mdf.to_csv('/data/dmart/output/p_data1.csv', sep="|" ,index=False)df.col.tolist()
```

output csv file p_data1.csv:

```
d_ph_num|r_vid|u_id
9812345670,9123456200|DQR695919,DQR695921,DQR696123,DQR69124,DQR695763,DQR695623,DQR69125,DQR696234,DQR695128|202000001
9123456914|DQR626679|202000002
|DQR040140|202000003
9123456174|DQR041822|202000004
```